# Angular 10: Import using module alias not resolved / Path Mapping not recognised in VSCode

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

So I updated a project that was in Angular 8.2 (a project template) to version 10 and followed the instructions from https://update.angular.io/ and everything was ok, but when implemented Path Mapping the pain started, I'm getting this error everywhere:

```
Cannot find module '@environments/environment' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)
```

And this error applies to **@environments** and **@modules**, which are declared in paths, the others does not show any error cause they are not in use.

Right now the project is building correctly when use **ng build**, haven't tried **ng build --prod**, no errors appear but **Visual Studio Code (v1.46.1)** is showing me the imports with errors, this is that I have:

**src/tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "files": [],
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.app.json"
    },
    {
      "path": "./e2e/tsconfig.json"
    }
  ]
}
```

**src/tsconfig.app.json**

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./lw/app",
    "types": []
  },
  "files": ["src/main.ts", "src/polyfills.ts"],
  "include": ["src/**/*.d.ts"],
  "exclude": ["src/test.ts", "src/**/*.spec.ts"]
}
```

**src/tsconfig.base.json**

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "outDir": "./dist/lw",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "es2020",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "lib": ["es2018", "dom"],
    "paths": {
      "@angular/*": ["./node_modules/@angular/*"],
      "@assets/*": ["assets/*"],
      "@environments/*": ["environments/*"],
      "@api/*": ["app/api/*"],
      "@components/*": ["app/components/*"],
      "@login/*": ["app/login/*"],
      "@models/*": ["app/models/*"],
      "@pages/*": ["app/pages/*"],
      "@services/*": ["app/services/*"],
      "@shared/*": ["app/shared/*"]
    }
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictTemplates": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

**NOTE: Have tried with "baseUrl": "src" and "baseUrl": "./src" and "baseUrl": "./" and nothing change.**

**Build Result**

```js
$ ng build
Generating ES5 bundles for differential loading...
ES5 bundle generation complete.

chunk {polyfills} polyfills-es2015.js, polyfills-es2015.js.map (polyfills) 141 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills-es5} polyfills-es5.js, polyfills-es5.js.map (polyfills-es5) 656 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {main} main-es2015.js, main-es2015.js.map (main) 12.2 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {main} main-es5.js, main-es5.js.map (main) 14.8 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {main} main-es2015.js, main-es2015.js.map (main) 12.2 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {main} main-es5.js, main-es5.js.map (main) 14.8 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles-es2015.js, styles-es2015.js.map (styles) 928 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles-es5.js, styles-es5.js.map (styles) 930 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime-es2015.js, runtime-es2015.js.map (runtime) 6.16 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime-es5.js, runtime-es5.js.map (runtime) 6.16 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor-es2015.js, vendor-es2015.js.map (vendor) 2.16 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor-es5.js, vendor-es5.js.map (vendor) 2.51 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {scripts} scripts.js, scripts.js.map (scripts) 167 kB [entry] [rendered]
Date: 2020-07-03T02:50:44.017Z - Hash: aa2180f982b4b754ebb6 - Time: 8621ms
```

**VSCode info**

```
Version: 1.46.1 (user setup)
Commit: cd9ea6488829f560dc949a8b2fb789f3cdc05f5d
Date: 2020-06-17T21:13:20.174Z
Electron: 7.3.1
Chrome: 78.0.3904.130
Node.js: 12.8.1
V8: 7.8.279.23-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.18363
```

**Angular CLI**

```
     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/
    

Angular CLI: 10.0.1
Node: 12.18.1
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 10.0.2
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.1000.1
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.1000.1
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.1000.1
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.1000.1
@angular-devkit/core              10.0.1
@angular-devkit/schematics        10.0.1
@angular/cli                      10.0.1
@ngtools/webpack                  10.0.1
@schematics/angular               10.0.1
@schematics/update                0.1000.1
rxjs                              6.5.5
typescript                        3.9.6
webpack                           4.43.0
```

Also here is a picture of how my project is organized

[image]

Also one really weird thing that happens is for example I have 2 Services (I'm having the problems in every Service) one **CityService** (which is in use) and **ColorService** (which is not in use), **CityService** is not showing any error and I can access the module definition (F12), but in **ColorService** with the same structure the problems appear and are in red.

[image]

[image]

Comment: did you get solution for this I am also facing same issue.

Answer (score 4):

**I have resolved this with below changes.**

1. Copy all code the from `tsconfig.base.json` or `tsconfig.app.json` to `tsconfig.json` file and remove `tsconfig.base.json` or `tsconfig.app.json`.
2. Change the path of `tsconfig.app.json` or `tsconfig.base.json` extends to

   ```
    {
    "extends": "../tsconfig.json" 
    ...
    }
   ```

Below is the code of `tsconfig.json` file.

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "module": "es2020",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "strict": false,
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@app-models": [
        "src/app/model/index"
      ],     
      "@app-core": [
        "src/app/core/index"
      ],
      "@app-shared": [
        "src/app/shared/index"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

3. 

A) If you have an active ng serve, restart the ng serve

```
CTRL + C
ng serve
```

B) If you don't have an active ng serve, do this:

```
Command + Shift + P
Search for "TypeScript: Restart TS Server"
Hit enter
```

Comment: I restarted TS Server and it didn't help. But remember, be sure to restart VS Code. Now it works, thanks!

Comment: After investigating a lot of other solutions this did the trick for me. Running tsc resolved all the modules correctly, but I was still getting ts compiler error in VS code until I renamed tsconfig.base.json to tsconfig.json.

Comment: thank you TypeScript: Restart TS Server is what fixed everything for me. didn't have to do any changes other than that

Answer (score 1):

Please try to change

'environments/environment'

To

'src/environments/environment'

Comment: still not working man, this didn't make any change.

Comment: Been trying but seems to be a Visual Studio Code issue

Answer (score 0):

There is one more scenario similar to the question being asked. Its not same as OP though. I am just posting the Q and A here.

On angular 13, If you rename some files which are imported or rename the export class then sometimes the angular cli stops recognizing the imports with @features etc...

Tried few different things. But then just thought of deleting the .angular folder in root as its something new used for caching. And then again did npm start. Now it started recognizing the renamed imports.